# .NET Core custom columns in Serilog PostgresSql sink

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-postgresql

I am using Serilog in my .NET Core application. I have added custom columns to the default list of columns.

This is my configuration:

`appsettings.json`:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:\\Logs\\logs.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:\\Logs\\logs.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "PostgreSQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "my-connection",
          "tableName": "public.mylogs",
          "needAutoCreateTable": true,
          "batchPostingLimit": 1,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate" ],
          "customColumns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "username",
            "DataType": "varchar",
            "DataLength": 50
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    ],

    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithThreadId"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "Shamis-Radio-Control-System"
    }
  },
```

`Program.cs`:

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", true, true)
        //.AddCommandLine(args)
        //.AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    // Configure serilog
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting up...");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        Log.Information("Shutting down...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Api host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                //.UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                .UseSerilog();
            });
```

This is my controller:

```
try
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("username", "Waleed"))
    {
        _ILogger.LogInformation("{Message}", "Starting up...");
    }     
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("username", "User1"))
    {
        _ILogger.LogInformation("{Message}", "Starting up...");
    }           
}
```

Running the project will generate the new table `mylogs`, but not delete column `MessageTemplate` and not generate custom column `username`.

I try added manually column "username" but always  the value null.

Please help me to resolve this issue - thanks all.

Comment: any Solution ... ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you found the solution but, this could help you.
Install nugets: **Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL** and **Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration**.

Add SelfLog to see errors if any (not necessary but can help you):

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
```

Here is configuration you can adjust (add or remove columns, change ColumnWriters...):

```
    "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration" ], // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithEnvironmentUserName",
      "WithExceptionDetails",
      "WithDemystifiedStackTraces"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "PostgreSQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "User ID='yyyyyy';Password=xxxxx;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DbName;Pooling=true;",
          "tableName": "\"Logs\"",
          "needAutoCreateTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Columns": {
    "\"Message\"": "RenderedMessageColumnWriter",
    "\"MessageTemplate\"": "MessageTemplateColumnWriter",
    "\"Level\"": {
      "Name": "LevelColumnWriter",
      "Args": {
        "renderAsText": true,
        "dbType": "Varchar"
      }
    },
    "\"TimeStamp\"": "TimestampColumnWriter",
    "\"Exception\"": "ExceptionColumnWriter",
    "\"Properties\"": "LogEventSerializedColumnWriter",
    "\"PropsTest\"": {
      "Name": "PropertiesColumnWriter",
      "Args": {
        "dbType": "Json"
      }
    },
    "\"MachineName\"": {
      "Name": "SinglePropertyColumnWriter",
      "Args": {
        "propertyName": "MachineName",
        "writeMethod": "Raw"
      }
    }
  }
```

Check this link also: https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql